# Why don't I get a method error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a rails programmer. And rails always tells me that I've got "NoMethodError". Why don't I get a MethodError? I want a MethodError.

Please help me.

Edit:

Here's my code:

```
42.this_is_a_method
```

Comment: Show us how you get a `NoMethodError` with Rails.

Comment: Please tell me this isn't a joke.

Comment: @jleedev , i'm starting to get the same feeling

Comment: @jleedev: I'm not 100% sure either way, but Java has `java.lang.NoSuch.MethodError`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have a MethodError. But you can make one!

```
class MethodError < NoMethodError; end
```

Now, catch all the NoMethodErrors in this way:

```
class Object
  def method_missing(m)
    raise MethodError, "undefined method `#{m}' for #{self.inspect}:#{self.class}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Much too complicated. Just do `MethodError = NoMethodError`.

Comment: @Joerg: If you raised a `MethodError`, you'd get `NoMethodError: NoMethodError`. That's because `MethodError.name` would return `NoMethodError`.

Answer (score 3):

You would be getting a `NoMethodError` because the `Fixnum` class doesn't have a `this_is_a_method` defined for instances of that class.